# How do I get Microsoft Edge to click on SAVE AS with Python

Tags: python, windows, automation

In our company we are using Selenium for web-automation on Windows. Win runs with signed-in user and locked screen. Recently company changed security for not starting downloading automatically. I need to click with Python on **Save As** button (while Windows is locked => pyautogui is not a option). What about pywinauto or other lib? thx

[image]

Comment: Automating browsers is done using Selenium and WebDriver, not GUI automation tools. What does `while Windows is locked` mean? That you want to run a scheduled job or service?

Comment: On the other hand, if you have the URL to a file you don't need the browser

Comment: Please look through some of these links to understand and implement: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-selenium-find-button-by-text/?ref=lbp

Comment: https://datatofish.com/python-script-windows-scheduler/

Answer (score 0):

If you can still use Selenium, try this out:

> **NOTE** - Tested using Windows 11, Edge 97, Python 3.9, and Selenium 4.1

```
import os
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service

# 'executable_path' is deprecated. Use 'service'
driver = webdriver.Edge(
    service=Service("C:\\Users\\kabarto\\Documents\\webdrivers\\msedgedriver.exe"))

driver.get("https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/")

# Find the link and use .click to save to Downloads
driver.find_element(
    By.XPATH,
    "//a[@href=\"https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/97.0.1072.62/edgedriver_win64.zip\"]"
).click()

# Close browser when download is complete
while not os.path.exists("C:\\Users\\kabarto\\Downloads\\edgedriver_win64.zip"):
    time.sleep(1)
driver.quit()
```

You can also get a list of all the links, and then go through them to find the one you want:

```
links = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a")
for l in links:
    if "win64" in l.get_attribute("href"):
        print(l.get_attribute("href"))
```

Comment: Hi Rob, the page does not contain a link to file, it is generated after the click on download button. However I found workaround... Thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out (work around):

1. Before downloading, to open a new tab with Edge Downloads
2. To launch downloading (getting pop-up)
3. To active tab with Downloads and with Selenium click on particular option (Cancel Save Save As ....)